# MVC custom helper appending htmlAttributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a custom helper class to highlight the selected menu item,

```
<li class="nav-item">
    @Html.MenuLink("Contact000", "Contact", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })
</li>
```

I want to use the helper htmlattributes and append to CSS if selected condition is true. I have seen a  [Similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246378/how-to-merge-htmlattributes-in-custom-helper) but was not able to find a question using

```
var attrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
```

Here is my code

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string text, string action, string controller, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var routeData = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
    var currentController = routeData["controller"];
    var currentAction = routeData["action"];

    var attrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

    if (String.Equals(action, currentAction as string,
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        &&
        String.Equals(controller, currentController as string,
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        if (attrs.ContainsKey("class"))
        {
            attrs["class"] += " " + "currentMenuItem";
        }

        return helper.ActionLink(text, action, controller, attrs);
    }

    return helper.ActionLink(text, action, controller, htmlAttributes);
}
```

using

```
 var attrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
```

I can append to the attributes.

when I return the helper.actionlink the attrs is not parsed correctly, below is the html generated,

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a Count="1" Keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]" Values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]" href="/Home/Contact?Length=4">Contact000</a>
</li>
```

I am trying to get the following,

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link currentMenuItem" href="/Home/Contact">Contact000</a>
</li>
```

How do I convert attrs back into htmlAttributes for the helper to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [`RouteValueDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) using `object htmlAttributes`. Then you can append a value like you would with any other [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

```
IDictionary<string, object> attrs = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);

string key = "key";
string oldValue;
if (attrs.TryGetValue(key, out oldValue))
{
    // append to value
    attrs[key] = oldValue + "string to append";
}
else
{
    // key not in attrs, handle accordingly
}
```

---

Full example:

```
using System.Web.Routing;

public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper helper,
    string text, string action, string controller, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var routeData = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
    var currentController = routeData["controller"];
    var currentAction = routeData["action"];

    IDictionary<string, object> attrs = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);

    if (String.Equals(action, currentAction as string,
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        && String.Equals(controller, currentController as string,
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        string clazz;
        if (attrs.TryGetValue("class", out clazz))
        {
            attrs["class"] = clazz + " " + "currentMenuItem";
        }
        // do you need to handle the case when there is no "class" attribute?

        return helper.ActionLink(text, action, controller, attrs);
    }

    return helper.ActionLink(text, action, controller, htmlAttributes);
}
```

---

**EDIT:** I found the actual issue to your problem, you are using the wrong 
`Html.ActionLink` overload.

You are currently using the [`ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, Object, Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) overload, when you should be using the [`ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, RouteValueDictionary, IDictionary<String, Object>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29) overload.

```
helper.ActionLink(text, action, controller, routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: attrs);
```

Comment: The problem is still with the rendered format of **attrs** in return `helper.ActionLink(text, action, controller, attrs);`

Comment: for some reason the `helper.ActionLink(text, action, controller, attrs);` is not converting the `attrs` to an object, the output is still in format `                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a Count="1" Keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]" Values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]" href="/?Length=4">Home</a>
                   
                </li>`

Comment: @user2668812 I've updated my answer, I believe you are using the wrong `Html.ActionLink` overload.